# CefSharp: JavaScript fetch() call doesn't make the pre-flight OPTIONS call

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Using CefSharp version 71.

While making fetch() call from JavaScript, it should ideally make the pre-flight  OPTIONS call before making the GET/POST call.

But it doesn't actually make it.
But if I try it in the Chrome browser, it does.

Tried this on Chrome browser, and it does make the pre-flight OPTIONS call.

The result of this is, since OPTIONS call is not made, CORB is stopping the response. 
The error is:
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://some-api.com/blah with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: Version `71` is old and unsupported, try with version `75`.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem with `75` then you should post on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php

Comment: I'll also point out that if you are using a custom scheme to make fetch requests you need to enable them explicitly using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefCustomScheme_IsFetchEnabled.htm requires at least version 75.

Comment: Was asked https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=17039

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `WebSecurity` is set to disabled in your `BrowserSettings`.

```
browserPlay.BrowserSettings = new BrowserSettings()
{
    WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled
};
```

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Add the above code in the application
2. Make a cross origin GET Request, notice that the request is made without "Origin:" header and Response does not have CORS headers.
3. In console, you will see the following CORB error: `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response`
4. I tested the above on CEF version `73.1.13`

Comment: Enabling web security seems like the exact opposite of what you'd want to do to fix this issue, but I can confirm that it works. If web security is disabled, the client side script won't send the "origin" header, which in turn prevents the server from returning the origin response header. Thus, the browser won't provide the respond data.